# XNA 2D sound effect mouse hovering

Tags: c#, xna

Working on a game here and I've so far made a menu system for my game. I added three different buttons. I have everything sorted out except one thing.

So, I am using a normal if intersects method to see if the mouse and the button rectangle is colliding to play a sound effect. However, I don't know how to stop this sound and it's just looping itself all the time, until I remove the mouse from the button. I want to make it so that it only plays one time.

```
public void Update(MouseState mouse, GraphicsDevice graphics, SoundEffect soundEffect)
{
    rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, (int)size.X, (int)size.Y);

    Rectangle mouseRectangle = new Rectangle(mouse.X, mouse.Y, 1, 1);

    if(mouseRectangle.Intersects(rectangle))
    {
        if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) isClicked = true;
        size = new Vector2(graphics.Viewport.Width / 9, graphics.Viewport.Height / 13);
        soundEffect.Play();
    }

    else
    {
        size = new Vector2(graphics.Viewport.Width / 10, graphics.Viewport.Height / 14);
        isClicked = false;
    }
```

Any help would be apreciated.

BTW: This is not neccesary, but I got another "problem" when I hover over the buttons, they get bigger which is intended. But it doesn't get bigger from the center. It's kind of hard to explain but it gets bigger in x and y position, not -x and -y. It has the same positon.

Comment: I think sounds have a `.looping` boolean property. Try setting it to false.

Comment: As for the buttons, when the cursor first intersects with them, also change their position by half the size difference to top-left. Like `button.position -= new Vector2(diff/2, diff/2)` and then do the opposite when leaving the button.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to employ some status fields or events to do what you want. Something simple might be to track when the mouse enters and leaves the rectangle:

```
private bool _mouseIsIntersecting;

public void Update(...)
{
    rectangle = new Rectangle(...);

    Rectangle mouseRectangle = new Rectangle(...);

    if(mouseRectangle.Intersects(rectangle))
    {
        // Handle click and size stuff

        // Only play the sound if mouse was not previously intersecting
        if (!_mouseIsIntersecting)
            soundEffect.Play();
        _mouseIsIntersecting = true;
    }
    else
    {
        _mouseIsIntersecting = false;

        // Handle other stuff
    }
}
```